# How to invoke another chaincode from one chaincode in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to work on a POC which would require this:

-Transaction from BusinessNetwork#1 should call another transaction from BusinessNetwork#2

For now, I'm only trying to make 2 Networks with same data, in which if change data in one network, the other should automatically reflect that change.

I have been trying to use the nativeApi().invokeChainCode() function, but I dont know how to use that to call custom created  transaction functions.

Help really appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial that should help you get started
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network

However you should be aware that if the business networks are on different channels you can only query the other business network, you will not be able to update the other business network. For that they must be on the same channel.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have gone through that tutorial. It works as it is. But when I try to change the arguments, it throws error saying either "first argument must be of type string" or "the function xxx with arguments xxx is not supported."       I can't understand, how composer written transaction function gets converted to fabric chaincode function.  Say I have a transaction which takes one participant and one asset in composer , how do i represent it in invokeChaincode() function?

Answer (score 0):

I have exploited console.log() and found out a solution.

```
const asset = '{
  "$class": "org.example.mynetwork.Trade",
  "commodity": "resource:org.example.mynetwork.Commodity#0518",
  "newOwner": "resource:org.example.mynetwork.Trader#4530"
}'

await getNativeAPI().invokeChaincode('other-tutorial-network', ['submitTransaction', 
asset]);
```

Here, other-tutorial-network is the name of the business network / name of the chaincode.

I guess the transaction functions that we create in composer always goes under 'submitTransaction()' function for fabric and takes the JSON like string as arguments.